# Efficiently calculating all pythagorean triples knowing the hypoteneuse

Tags: c#, math, pythagorean

Given a hypoteneuse (`c` in the typical equation `a*a + b*b = c*c`), what is an efficient way to calculate all possible integer values of `a` and `b`, such that `a < b`?

Note: I've seen `c` be greater than `1e12`, thus `c*c` is greater than `long.MaxValue`, from what I can tell, `c*c` does fit into a `decimal`, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a mathematical solution that finds a and b fast even for large values of c.
Unfortunately, it is not that simple. I'm trying to give a short explanation of the algorithm. I hope it is not too confusing.

Since c is given and you are looking for a and b, you basically want to solve diophantine
equations of the form

```
n=x^2+y^2,
```

where n is given. It doesn't help much that n = c*c is a square and thus I'm describing a solution for any n. If n were a prime number then you could use
[Fermat's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares), to decide if your equation is solvable, and use, as Moron pointed out the Hermite-Serret algoritm to find the solutions if there are any.

To solve the case where n is not prime it is a good idea to use
[Gaussian integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer). (Gaussian integers are just complex numbers with integral coefficients). In particular one notes that the *norm* of x+yi is

```
N(x+yi) = x^2+y^2.
```

Hence one has to find the Gaussian integers x+yi whose norm is n.
Since the norm is is multiplicative it is sufficient to solve this equation for the factors of n and then to multiply the Gaussian integers of the individal equations.
Let me give an example. We want to solve

```
65 = x^2 + y^2.
```

This is equivalent to find x,y such that

```
N(x+yi) = 65
```

over the Gaussian integers. We factor 65 = 5 * 13, then we use Fermat to note that both
5 and 13 can be represented as sum of two squares. Finally, we find either by using brute force of by using the Hermite-Serret algorithm

```
N(2+i) = N(1+2i) = ... = 5
N(2+3i) = N(3+2i) = ... = 13
```

Note, I've left out the Gaussion integers 2-i, -2+i, etc with negative coefficients.
Those are of course solutions too.

Hence we can now multiply these solutions together to get

65 = 5*13 = N(2+i) * N(2+3i) = N((2+i) * (2+3i)) = N(1 + 8i)

and

65 = 5 * 13 = N(2+i) * N(3+2i) = N((2+i) * (3+2i)) = N(4 + 7i).

Hence, one gets the two solutions

```
1*1 + 8*8 = 65
4*4 + 7*7 = 65
```

The other combinations e.g. with negative coefficients need to be checked too.
They don't give new solutions other than permutations and changed signs.

---

To compute all the solutions one might also add that there is no need to ever compute c*c.
Finding the factors of c is all that is necessary. Also since a and b are both smaller than c, it will not happen that products of Gaussian integers are not representable with 64-bit integer coefficients. Hence, if one is careful, 64-bit integer are enough precision to solve the problem. Of course, it is always easier to just use a language like Python that does not have this kind of overflow problems.

Comment: Just to add to this:
To compute the gaussian factors of primes of the form 4n+1, use the Hermite-Serret algorithm.

Primes of form 4n+3 are gaussian primes, so there is no further need to factorize them.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks a lot. I've added the Hermite-Serret algorithm to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

All pythagorean triples (a,b,c) satisfy the property that, for some integers k,m and n,

a=k(m^2-n^2), b=2kmn, c=k(m^2 + n^2)

So start by factoring c.  Then for every distinct factor k of c (i.e. for every distinct subset of the factors, multiplied together), find all m and n that satisfy c/k = (m^2 + n^2).  Doing the latter will take significantly less time than the brute-force approach others have suggested (you only have to find squares that sum to c/k, instead of c^2), but will identify all triples (a,b,c).  You also don't need to use bignums, because all of the intermediate results fit into a long.

I also suggest you check out the web page http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Pythag/pythag.html under the heading "A more general Pythagorean Triple Calculator" which contains an embedded calculator, written in javascript, that does precisely what you want.

Comment: I think there is a k missing in b.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well go for a BigNum library.

As for an efficient way of finding a and b:

For each value of b (starting at c-1 and going down until b * b < c * c / 2), calculate c * c - b * b, and then check if it's a perfect square.

Comment: The problem is that if c = 1e12, then I'd still need to do 2.92e11 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a value of 1 for a and a value of c for b.

Compare `c*c - b*b` to `a*a`. If they are equal, you have a match.

Change a and b towards each other depending on what side is larger, until they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Given a c:

Since b > a, if a is minimum (a = 1), b = sqrt(c*c - 1).

Therefore b MUST be between that value and c -1.

Also, since b must be an integer, you need to find the first value for which this is an integer.

```
Now, a property of squares:
The squares are: 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, ...
The differences: -, 3, 5, 07, 09, 11, 13, 15, 17, 019, 021, ...
That means a square can be written as a summation of ODD numbers:
    1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + n+...
where n = number the summation is a square of.
```

So there are exactly c square numbers less than c*c, and you can identify them using simple subtraction.

Back to the beginning, taking b = sqrt(c*c - 1), rounding down and taking b*b, we get the square b must be above, and a*a = 1.  Find c*c - (a*a + b*b).  This should give you the number that must be ADDED to achieve c*c.

Since you can add `3 + 5 + 7 + ...` to a, and `b+2 + b+4 + b+6 + ...` to b, you just have to find the right term based on the sums rather than the square itself :)